# Xcode 9 font & colors preferences not preserved after restarting

Tags: xcode, ide, xcode9

Xcode > Preferences > Fonts & Colors > Plus Button > Duplicate Theme > Name The New Theme > Update The New Scheme > Close Preferences > Coffee & Code > Kill Xcode > Launch Xcode > Preferences > Fonts & Colors > New Theme Missing!?!

Xcode Version 9.2 (9C40b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could duplicate the xccolortheme file without a problem. The issue was permissions. It had the wrong permissions! What the deuce!

Comment: Yep, this was the exact problem for me!.. man took so much time. I had to change the permission of "staff" to read and write it started to work

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce the problem you've described, the theme I created was preserved after killing and re-launching Xcode. Interestingly, my custom theme was moved to **the bottom of the list**, maybe that's the case for you as well.

If your theme legitimately went missing, it can be because of a software or a hardware bug/fault. What you can do is make a backup from your .xccolortheme file before quitting Xcode to make sure that it survives the relaunch.

For this, you should navigate to

**~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/FontAndColorThemes/**

and make a copy of the file you want to preserve. If it ever disappears, you can move the copy back to this location.

Comment: Hi @the4kman thanks for the response. I'm afraid I followed your suggestions to no avail. Making a backup has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem in Xcode 10. It was caused by the name I gave the theme: `AI/ML`. I headed to `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/FontAndColorThemes/`, the directory in which the themes are stored, as pointed to by [Tamás Sengel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48964273/7395227).

In `FontAndColorThemes`, there was a directory named `AI`, containing the theme, with the name `ML`. I moved the theme one level up, deleted the directory, and renamed the theme file. I then had to restart Xcode again, to get the theme back on the list.

Xcode read `/` not as part of the name, but as a separator between a directory and the file. Xcode should've managed this situation, but as it doesn't, don't name your files this way; at least I won't.